# Core 2.0 SignInManager.IsSignedIn

Tags: asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

Good day,

I'm puzzled at this issue, because I had this working nicely for me before I upgraded to Core 2.0. My app has (or had!) two sign in options, one calling Azure AD for internal users, and another using Identity for external users to register / login. (I use `ClaimsTransformer` to add claims to AD users from the app's claims database.

My _LoginPartial looks like this:

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))

        {
            ... display @User.GetFirstName() and log out button
...
}

    else if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
    ... Display AD's @User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value and sign out button
}

else
{
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
                   <li class="nav-item"><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" class="nav-link">Register</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item"><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn" class="nav-link">Internal Log in</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-item"><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" class="nav-link">External Log in</a>
                   </li>  </ul>
}
```

This produced the desired effect with Core 1.1. However, now I can't seem to get `SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)` to return true (which is what happened previously for external sign ins.

My `Startup.cs` looks like so:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>

            {
                ...
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<JCContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Account/LogIn");

        services.AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })

            .AddOpenIdConnect(option =>
            {
                option.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAD:ClientId"];
                option.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:Authority"];
                option.CallbackPath = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:CallbackPath"];

            })
            .AddCookie(o =>
            {
                o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/LogIn");
                o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
                o.LogoutPath = "/Account/LogOut";
            });
```

The funny thing is, if I put `services.AddAuthentication(...)` *before* `services.AddIdentity`, I get the opposite effect. My external user can show 'signed in', but `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` doesn't return `true` when AD users log in.

I've gone back and forth rearranging the items in startup but I can't seem to find the winning combination.Am I missing something obvious? There must be something about the SignInManager / cookies I'm not understanding.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you replaced `app.UseIdentity` to `app.UseAuthentication()` in the `Configure` method?

Comment: I have indeed. It took a while but I finally upgraded the app to get everything else working (so far!), just not this niggle.

Comment: Maybe then you can answer your own question to help others in the future.

Comment: I wish I could, but the SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User) problem persists. I most certainly will when I can.

Answer (score 0):

I also create a project to integrate with Azure AD and individual accounts which works well for me. And here is the code in the `ConfigureServices` method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Account/Manage");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Account/Logout");
        });

    // Register no-op EmailSender used by account confirmation and password reset during development
    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532713
    services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = String.Format(Configuration["AzureAd:AadInstance"], Configuration["AzureAd:Tenant"]);
        options.ClientId = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
    });
}
```

I also have uploaded the demo project to GitHub, you can download it from [this link](https://github.com/VitorX/webappLocalAccountAAD) and compare the difference with your code.

Comment: Thanks, this is great to know! So this is strange, I pulled your solution, plugged in my credentials and it works just fine as I'd hope. 
Something weird is going on with mine though. following your Startup I can get the external login just fine, but when I sign in with Azure, I seem to hit a sort of infinite loop when trying to access a restricted view - hard to explain - it has the cookie, but it doesn't say signed in up top, and it keeps redirecting and trying again.

Comment: Would you mind sharing a demo code to help us to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Hopefully you can pull from [here](https://github.com/mikustykus/SampleProject/tree/a788ef600d5162956647c03fc633e4d26a3f57f4/src/JC) and I figure if you plug in a db string and some open Id keys, you should at least be able to reproduce this eternal redirect scenario. If you 'sign in' with open id, then try to access the 'authorised area'. For me it goes blank, but inspecting in chrome on the network tab shows this funny behaviour.  (it works ok with Identity log in). It's probably something obvious, but I love to know what's causing that (and if there's a fix!)

Comment: Just on the off-chance, did you ever think of / spot and reason this should behave differently in my app from yours?  I'm starting to think I may have to rebuild from the ground up again, but would be a sham if it was just something obvious.

Comment: I revisited this after all this time time, and finally got it working in the way you described, so thank you. One thing though, I don't seem to get any of the Azure AD claims that I used to get. I suspect that is a limitation of this dual authentication method?